# how to allow only positive numbers in numeric filter in grid in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

Its my first post, so i may be posting in wrong thread, sorry for that.

I would like to restrict negative values in numeric grid filter, allowing only positive numbers in numeric filter in grid, I am not able to find how to do this.

here is my code

```
var myFilters =
{
    ftype     : 'filters',
    encode    : false,
    local     : false,
    extend    : 'Ext.data.Model',          
    filters    :
    [
        {
            type        : 'numeric',
            dataIndex    : 'utilization_per'
        }
    ]
};

deviceUtilGridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel(
{
    features    : [myFilters],
    columns :
    [
          {id:'ru_utilization_per', header: "Utilization(%) (U)", sortable: true,     dataIndex: 'utilization_per', filterable: true, filter :{type:'numeric'},width:80}
    ]
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `menuItemCfgs` config on the filter to modify the form field used by the filter menu.

```
var myFilters = {
    ftype:   "filters",
    encode:  false,
    local:   false,
    filters: [{
        dataIndex:    "utilization_per",
        type:         "numeric",
        menuItemCfgs: {
            minValue: 1  // Or 0, or whatever you want
        }
    }]
};
```

As a side note (not really related to the answer), your code has a few issues with it. You don't need to add `extend` to your filter config because you're not extending it, and it doesn't need to know about your models. The `header` config in your column definition has been deprecated in favor of `text` which does the same thing. Columns are filterable by default so you don't need `filterable: true`. And if you specify your column filter in the filter feature config, you don't need to specify it on the column level.